# Mains: If I measure 30 VAC on a switched-off circuit, is it more likely that one wire is floating or "partly energized"?

Tags: mains, floating

It's a 3-way switch circuit powering an LED light bulb. I don't know how possible it is for a wire to be partly-hot at some level between 0 and 110 V. I know that floating voltages show up as something greater than 0, usually fluctuating a bit, but I don't know how high they can realistically read as.

An electrician already looked at it and said he wasn't worried about safety but didn't offer any insight about what was happening ("this just happens and it's nothing to worry about"). So right now I'm more interested in understanding what's happening than whether it's safe or not.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are measuring capacitivly-coupled voltage on one of the "strapper" (UK term) wires which is disconnected at both end so it is floating. You are probably using a digital multimeter with an input impedance of 10 MΩ on the AC volts range. That's high enough not to load the wire. If you switch the lamp to that wire it will pull it to neutral and the voltage will collapse.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHlQIx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) A voltage may be read between NODE1 and neutral due to capacitance between the floating wire and the wire connected to live. (b) Connecting the lamp will cause the voltage to collapse.*

The 30 V is very weak as the impedance (AC resistance) of the capacitance is so high.

---

Tip: "3-way switch" is an American term for what most would term a two-way switch (up or down). The confusion arises as it has three terminals rather than two in a normal on/off switch.